# Profile Image Styling - With No Image Stretch - CSS

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I am using simple css code for **Profile Image** Styling, but Image is **stretched**. How can i fix it?

**Take a look at the Profile Images in this Picture:**

[image]

Right Now I am Using this Code:

```
.Comment_Image_Size {
    height: 32px;
    width: 28px;
}
```

I also used this Code but in this case some Images are **Bigger** and some are **smaller** in height:

```
.Comment_Image_Size {
    width: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fix the image dimensions, I think the project you are working on should be dynamic, if it's yes, than you can also resize the images via server side, if you don't want to do that, and want to stick with HTML and CSS, than use a wrapping element, say `div`, `float` it to the `left`, assign some fix `height` & `width` and assign a `class`, and than use the below snippet to

```
div.class_name img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

This way, your image will resize proportionally and it won't be stretched anymore

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7V4sR/2/) (I've attached both examples, you can check out in the demo)

In the above demo, the first one is which I've suggested to you, other is one which you are probably doing, which is stretched, so go for `max-height` and `max-width` properties.

Comment: Cant see images in it

Comment: You needed to open the image URL manually, then it was chached and got displayed. Otherwise it redirected to an HTML site. Now it works for me.

Comment: The Image at bottom is stretched

Comment: @Necromancer Yes, the upper one is what I suggested you, please read the answer properly :) and I've updated the link in my answer as well

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sorry my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

best solutoin to give max-width and max-height to your class

```
.Comment_Image_Size {
    max-width:28px;
    max-height:32px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the original images are not the same aspect ratio. You need to specify the right height and width for each image to ensure that the maximum width/height is not exceeded (one will be less if not the right aspect ratio).

You may need to resize the images upon upload to have thumbnails that are the right size while preserving the aspect ratio [How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio)