# How to resize the image proprtionally keeping the aspect ratio using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to resize the image proprtionally keeping the aspect ratio using jquery. Basically I want to add the code to adjust the top/left/width/height based on the ratio of the resized image

I tried this :

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    reposition();

    // add the code to adjust the top/left/width/height 
    // based on the ratio of the resized image
    var $carouselImg = $('.carouselImg');
    //alert($carouselImg.width());
    //alert($carouselImg.height());
    //code begin
    $('.carouselImg').each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 621; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 584;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if (width > maxWidth) {
            ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }

        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if (height > maxHeight) {
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        }
    });

});
```

I have two hubspots(place holders on the image points two different links), on the image. They also shrink when i resize them.. I want to the image shrink when viewed in small devices.

Comment: You need to explain what's wrong with you code. No one is going to go and run it just to debug it for you.

Comment: Try to look this answer:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio