# How to scale (resize) image keep aspect ratio in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some images with random dimension and the the question is how can I scale (resize) it to exactly 960×1280 for example in JavaScript, but keep image origin aspect ratio:

- If the image is **bigger** than the expected size, it is **scaled down** (keeping aspect ratio) and the empty areas are filled with transparent color.
- If the image is **smaller** than the expected size, it is **not scaled** but centered and the empty areas are filled with transparent color.

I had read some on this topic but still could not resolve the problem.

This is not working for me: [How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio/14731922#14731922)

UPDATED: Working solution here, many thank to @Mr. Polywhirl
[Update solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791548/4762384)

Comment: I'd used this method and some change to resize image to exactly expected dimension but it make image lose it ratio: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14731922/4762384)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code in a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for reminding

Comment: What part of the link you gave failed?

Comment: I'd try answer #2 by Jason Nathan

Comment: you can do this with css, no need for js

Comment: Thank you @Pete but I need to use js to do this and get the result image to be uploaded

Answer (score 2):

In order to figure out the aspect ratio to use for scaling, you need to figure out which dimension is larger. One you do that, you just divide the image width/height by the viewer's width/height and that should determine the scaling factor.

Centering can be achieved by finding the offset of the scaled image within the viewer.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('image-viewer').getContext('2d');
var images = [
  'http://i.imgur.com/5PF0Xdi.jpg',
  'http://i.imgur.com/po0fJFT.png',
  'http://i.imgur.com/Ijzdt0o.png'
];
var counter = 0;

// Load a new image after 2 seconds.
setInterval(function() {
  loadScaleAndCenterImage(ctx, images[counter++ % images.length]);
}, 2000);

function loadScaleAndCenterImage(ctx, url) {
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload   = function(e) {
    var ctxWidth    = ctx.canvas.width,
        ctxHeight   = ctx.canvas.height;
    var imgWidth    = imageObj.width,
        imgHeight   = imageObj.height;
    var ratioWidth  = imgWidth  / ctxWidth,
        ratioHeight = imgHeight / ctxHeight,
        ratioAspect = ratioWidth > 1 ? ratioWidth : ratioHeight > 1 ? ratioHeight : 1;
    var newWidth    = imgWidth / ratioAspect,
        newHeight   = imgHeight / ratioAspect;
    var offsetX     = (ctxWidth  / 2) - (newWidth  / 2),
        offsetY     = (ctxHeight / 2) - (newHeight / 2);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctxWidth, ctxHeight);
    ctx.drawImage(this, offsetX, offsetY, newWidth, newHeight);
  };

  imageObj.src = url;
}
```

```css
#image-viewer {
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, #7F7F7F 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #7F7F7F 75%, #7F7F7F), 
    linear-gradient(45deg, #7F7F7F 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #7F7F7F 75%, #7F7F7F);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px
}
```

```html
<canvas id="image-viewer" width="1280" height="960"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Basically its mostly css, but we use JS to get the image dimensions. If either dimension is greater than our bounds (x>960 or y>1280), set the css propeprty `background-size:contain`

```js
    var onload = function () {
//grab image dimensions on load
        var w = this.width;
        var h = this.height;
        if (w > 960 || h > 1280) {
//set contain if needed
            document.getElementById(this.dataset.div)
                    .style.backgroundSize = "contain";
        }
    };
//grab all the container divs
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
//iterate thru them
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];
        var img = new Image;
//set the id of the current div as a data attribute of the img, 
//so we can reference it in the onload function
        img.dataset.div = div.id;
//apply onload function
        img.onload = onload;
//set the img src to the background image. use a quick regex to extract 
//just the img url from the whole "url(img.ext)" string
        img.src = getComputedStyle(div, 0).backgroundImage
                .match(/url\(['"]?([a-z0-9\/:.]+)['"]{0,1}/i)[1];
    }
```

```css
div.container{
width:960px;
height:1280px;
border:1px solid black;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:transparent;
/*background-image:url(/path/to/img.ext);*/
}
div#container-1{
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/5PF0Xdi.jpg);
}
div#container-2{
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/po0fJFT.png);
}
div#container-3{
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/Ijzdt0o.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container-1"></div>
<div class="container" id="container-2"></div>
<div class="container" id="container-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function for a collage maker and it works like a charm.

Just set the variable "*Size*" below to whatever image sizes (Width x Height in pixels) you want to set as ideal for all your images to approach, without losing their aspect ratio.

Your images will retain their exact shape but will either shrink or grow to meet "Size".

```
function ScaleImage(Img){

var Size=150000, nW=Img.naturalWidth, nH=Img.naturalHeight, W=nW, H=nH, Scale=1;

if((W*H)>Size){

 while((W*H)>Size){Scale-=0.01; W=nW*Scale; H=nH*Scale;}

} else {

 while((W*H)<Size){Scale+=0.01; W=nW*Scale; H=nH*Scale;}

} 

Img.width=Math.round(W); Img.height=Math.round(H);

}
```

Typical usage...

```
<img src="apples.jpg" onload="ScaleImage(this);">
```