# Way to turn 280x280 Pixel Image into 28x28. (Not display image just changing the file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project and I have an image from the user in the data:image/png form. I need it to be a 28x28 image. I'm trying to convert the 280x280 image from to user to 28x28, and then into a 784x1 array with each pixel value.

I have tried a number of packages and none of them seem to work.

Comment: How's this related to ReactJS?

Comment: I'm getting the image from the user on a react site I'm building, and trying to convert the image within the react code.

Comment: See [Resize image with javascript canvas (smoothly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly) and [Drawing an image from a data URL to a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale (resize) image keep aspect ratio in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790874/how-to-scale-resize-image-keep-aspect-ratio-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not trying to display the resized image in a canvas though, so nothing about canvases will help me. I'm just trying to get the image data into a 28x28 form so I can turn it into an array/tensor.

Answer (score 2):

So you're in a browser environment and have a `data:` URL describing an image? You don't need a package.

- Have the browser parse the URL and read it as an image with `i = new Image()`, `i.addEventListener("load", listener)`, `i.src = 'data:...'`.
- Within `listener`, create a `canvas = new HTMLCanvasElement()`, and set its dimensions (`width`, `height`) to 28x28. The element doesn't need to be in the document, we'll just use it to draw things.
- Call `ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")` to get a 2D drawing canvas.
- Call `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 28, 28)` to fill the canvas to a solid color, just in case the user's image contains an alpha channel you don't care about.. (Set `fillColor` first if black isn't your thing.)
- Call [`ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0, 28, 28)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to draw the original image onto your context.
- Call [`ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 28, 28)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to get an ImageData object describing the image.
- The ImageData object's [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) is now a 28 * 28 * 4 = 3136 byte array in RGBARGBARGBA... order. You wanted 784 (28 * 28 * 1) bytes, so either choose a channel (0, 1, 2) from the `data` and copy with that offset and a stride of 4 to a 784-byte `Uint8ClampedArray`, or average every 3 bytes to take a lazy grayscale of the RGB image data. (For a more correct grayscale, use e.g. `v = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b` for the [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Conversion_to/from_RGB) brightness scale.)
- Put the resulting 784-byte array where you need it to be.

(Since you mention you're working with tensors, and 28x28 sounds a lot like MNIST images, you may want to add additional logic to invert the grayscale if it looks like it's black-on-white; the MNIST images are white-on-black, and you'll get weird results if they're not the same.)

Comment: Thanks @AKX! I followed everything and it worked! I'm having a little trouble moving from the 3136 RGB(...) Array to the 784x1 array by "choosing a channel". I am working in MNIST, how do I convert/invert the grayscale?

Comment: To fill your 784-byte array, use a good ol' for loop, and assign `out[i] = imageData.data[i * 4]` to grab the first (red) channel of each pixel. If the original image is monochrome, it'll work out like that.