# Image resizing php

Tags: php, image

For the website I am building I need to resize some images to make web page loading lighter. I use this code:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img_path);
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50 * $height/$width);
    if($type == 2) $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_path);
    if($type == 3) $source = imagecreatefrompng($img_path);
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50 * $height/$width, $width, $height);
```

Now I could save them on the sever to keep them ready whenever necessary but considering the little space I have available I would rather avoid.

So my question is: is there a way to create a "temporary" image from the code I already have and use it inside an `<img>` tag?

For example `<img src="$img_resized"/>`.

Comment: Take a look at [TimThumb](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/)

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

That's called `Resizing Images on the Fly`

I suggest you use one of these libraries for this:

[meenie/munee](https://github.com/meenie/munee)

or

[mos/cimage](https://github.com/mosbth/cimage)

Install the library using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

`composer require meenie/munee` or `composer require mos/cimage`

Then you can link your photos by using one of these:

```
Meenie: <img src="/path/to/image.jpg?resize=width[100]">

cImage: <img src="/host/img.php?src=test.png&width=100">
```

Comment: Seems exactly what I need but is there any compatibility issue with Codeigniter framework? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, they are external to the framework, they should work okay