# Make a responsive rectangle in Konva (React Konva) that maintains aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio, konvajs, react-konva

In CSS, I can do it like:

```html
<div class="aspect-ratio-box"></div>
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.aspect-ratio-box {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background: red;
}
```

Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BZNoev). Try resizing the browser window to see how it maintains aspect ratio.

But I can't wrap my head around on how to do it with Konva, especially React Konva where I have to maintain aspect ratio using `width`, `height` & `aspectRatio`. There is no `padding-top`.

How should I do it?

**Note:** It looks similar to [How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio) but I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731922/6141587) & it jumps up from original position (width=1024, height=600) when I shrink the browser but when I grow it again it never returns to the original position (width=1024, height=600)

This is what I want my app to look like:

[image: browser-window]

Basically I want to accomplish the white part in the center in JS because I need to use Canvas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: @oguzhancerit nope, i already checked this solution → https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731922/6141587 which is close but the initial position (width=1024, height=600) is never obtained again. i would love to solve this but cant seem to figure out a way that doesn't use CSS's `padding-top` & can purely do it in JS but has output like https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BZNoev

Comment: @oguzhancerit i edited the question with an image..i've shown what im trying to accomplish if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a real cool solution that allows me to do it → https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731922/6141587

I adapted it to my needs:

```js
const maxWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.9
const maxHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.9
const width = 1366
const height = 768
const ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / width, maxHeight / height)

return {
  width: width * ratio,
  height: height * ratio,
}
```

**Edit:** This doesn't work as expected. Jumps up from original width & never returns back to the original width.

**Edit 2:** That's working as expected I assume. I was resetting my `width` to `width * 0.8` so it never came back to original width otherwise it probably works fine.

However I went with another simpler solution that worked just fine:

```js
const aspectRatio = 16 / 9
const width = window.innerWidth * 0.8
const height = width / aspectRatio

return {
  width,
  height,
}
```