# Resize image on hover but keep aspect ratio and inside screen

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transforms

this is meant to work only on desktop.

The thing is, even though I have managed to zoom images on hover and maintain aspect ratio, I can't manage to make a smooth hovering experience.

The images bounding box (or parent divs) are bigger than the images so when the users scroll out of the image the zoom effect keeps working (logically) plus the images at the right of the screen, get out of view when hovering.

How can I keep the aspect ratio, keep the images on screen, keep the rest of the content in place and zoom only when the user is hovering the image (back to default when the user stop hovering the image).

```css
.la-inversion {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.la-inversion__izquierda img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__titulo {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__subtitulo {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 71.5%;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vw;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha div {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 45vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000%;
  right: -1000%;
  top: -1000%;
  bottom: -1000%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 150%;
  max-height: 150%;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha div:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vw;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda div {
  height: 45vw;
  width: 45vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000%;
  right: -1000%;
  top: -1000%;
  bottom: -1000%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 150%;
  max-height: 150%;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda div:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

  .img-scale-div{
    transition: .3s;
  }
  .img-scale-img{
    transition: .3s;
  }
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

  .img-scale-div:hover {
    transform: scale(4, 4) translate(-2vw);
    z-index: 2;
    align-self: center;
    outline: groove;
  }
  .img-scale-div:hover > .img-scale-img {
    position: initial;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

.la-inversion {
    display: flex;
    -moz-column-gap: 7.5rem;
         column-gap: 7.5rem;
    width: calc( 100% - 9rem );
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20rem auto 0;
  }
  .la-inversion__izquierda {
    flex: 2 0 0;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha {
    flex: 1 0 0;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__subtitulo {
    margin-left: 0rem;
    width: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
         column-count: 2;
    font-size: 16px;
    -moz-column-gap: 2rem;
         column-gap: 2rem;
    -moz-column-width: 234px;
         column-width: 234px;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes {
    flex-direction: row;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
         column-gap: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 4rem;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha {
    height: 236px;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
         column-gap: 1.5rem;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha__titulo {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha div {
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda {
    height: 236px;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
         column-gap: 1.5rem;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda div {
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="la-inversion">

            <div class="la-inversion__izquierda">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/JktFp0J/imagen-vertical-inversion.png" alt="" >
            </div>

            <div class="la-inversion__derecha">
                <h2 class="la-inversion__derecha__titulo">1. La Inversión</h2>
                <p class="la-inversion__derecha__subtitulo">Rodeado de montañas, enclavado en un valle amplio con vegetación baja y autóctona que da la sensación de estar en plena estepa patagónica aunque en verdad nos encontramos dentro del bosque andino. <br><br>Suspendisse faucibus tincidunt pulvinar. Suspendisse quis tortor et sem lobortis auctor vehicula vitae libero. Aliquam nisl odio, sagittis.</p>
                <div class="la-inversion__derecha__imagenes">

                    <div class="la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha">
                        <div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img"  src="https://i.ibb.co/6R2XWkS/ba-o-vertical.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                        <div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img"  src="https://i.ibb.co/Jj5yHgt/ba-o-horizontal.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda">
                        <div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/SPpkq6Y/cocina-horizontal.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                        <div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wMQzXxT/living-horizontal.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get images natural sizes, for that you'll need a bit of javascript.
Feel free to use `dataset` to get initial size values from images, I simply wrote them like I'd write css.

```js
const onScaleImage = (e) => {
   const image = e.target.closest('.img-scale-img');
   
  if (image) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseover') {
       image.style.height = `${image.naturalHeight}px`;
       image.style.width = `${image.naturalWidth}px`; 
    } else {
      image.style.height = '118px';
      image.style.width = '118px'; 
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mouseover', onScaleImage)
document.addEventListener('mouseout', onScaleImage)
```

```css
.la-inversion {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.la-inversion__izquierda img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__titulo {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__subtitulo {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 71.5%;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha div {
  position: relative;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha div img {
      height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
      top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha div:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda div {
  position: relative;
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
   position: absolute;
  right: 0;
      top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda div:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

  .img-scale-div{
    transition: .3s;
  }
  .img-scale-img{
    transition: .3s;
  }
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.la-inversion {
    display: flex;
    -moz-column-gap: 7.5rem;
         column-gap: 7.5rem;
    width: calc( 100% - 9rem );
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20rem auto 0;
  }
  .la-inversion__izquierda {
    flex: 2 0 0;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha {
    flex: 1 0 0;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__subtitulo {
    margin-left: 0rem;
    width: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
         column-count: 2;
    font-size: 16px;
    -moz-column-gap: 2rem;
         column-gap: 2rem;
    -moz-column-width: 234px;
         column-width: 234px;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes {
    flex-direction: row;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
         column-gap: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 4rem;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha {
    height: 236px;
     display: flex;
    gap: 1.5rem;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha__titulo {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .img-scale-img:hover {
        outline: groove;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha .img-scale-div {
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda {
      height: 236px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.5rem;
  }
  .la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda .img-scale-div {
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="la-inversion">

            <div class="la-inversion__izquierda">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/JktFp0J/imagen-vertical-inversion.png" alt="" >
            </div>

            <div class="la-inversion__derecha">
                <h2 class="la-inversion__derecha__titulo">1. La Inversión</h2>
                <p class="la-inversion__derecha__subtitulo">Rodeado de montañas, enclavado en un valle amplio con vegetación baja y autóctona que da la sensación de estar en plena estepa patagónica aunque en verdad nos encontramos dentro del bosque andino. <br><br>Suspendisse faucibus tincidunt pulvinar. Suspendisse quis tortor et sem lobortis auctor vehicula vitae libero. Aliquam nisl odio, sagittis.</p>
                <div class="la-inversion__derecha__imagenes">

                    <div class="la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__derecha">
                        <div><div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img"  src="https://i.ibb.co/6R2XWkS/ba-o-vertical.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div></div>
                       <div> <div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img"  src="https://i.ibb.co/Jj5yHgt/ba-o-horizontal.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div></div>
                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="la-inversion__derecha__imagenes__izquierda">
                        <div><div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/SPpkq6Y/cocina-horizontal.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div></div>
                        <div><div class="img-scale-div"><img class="img-scale-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wMQzXxT/living-horizontal.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div></div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: hi @mttetc loved your solution for the flickering issue, yes the CSS is somehow messed up but it makes sense using SASS. thanks for the advice. I'm a little rusty.
The thing is, I don't want to crop the images on hover, but to show it full size, either if it's landscape or portrait, I want the full image to be shown. do you think that's possible?

Comment: I need to think about it

Comment: I updated the snippet, be aware that you have enormous sized images, maybe downsize them!

Comment: Thank you mttetc, yeah this is only a little part of a WordPress website, as I don´t know how the client is going to handle images I went for the worst-case scenario. to address this issue I have used your javascript combined with this method to resize and keep aspect ratio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio. Thank you for enlightening me. Works like a charm!