Resizing image on scroll
I'm trying to make a website and insert a logo that would change its size when the user scrolls. Right now I can't find the formula to make this applicable to different monitors (I can only manually input some coefficient that suits my monitor).
Here is what I wrote so far:
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = window.scrollY
            /*
            var testDiv = document.getElementById("trade"); //this element is the limit to where the picture should be resized (should be same as clients height)
            var move = testDiv.offsetTop-$(window).scrollTop()-66
            console.log(move)
            */
        //all in pixels (px)
        
            var newWidth = 1024 - scroll/1.128 //this number only works for my monitor 
            var newHeight = 223 - scroll/5  //same here
          
            var minWidth = 308; 
            if (newWidth < minWidth) {
                newWidth = minWidth;
            }
            var minHeight = 64;
            if (newHeight < minHeight) {
                newHeight = minHeight;
            }
        
        
            $(".navbar-brand img").css({
                width: newWidth + 'px',
                height: newHeight + 'px'
            });

           
            
        });

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "home">
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
            <div class = "container-fluid">
                <a href = "#home" class = "navbar-brand fixed-top" id="navbar-brand">
                    <img id="cover-image" src = "RECMAN-header.png" title = "home">
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="dataHeight">
        </div>
    </div>
        

    IMAGE SHOULD BE AT ITS SET SIZE (308x64) BEFORE HERE

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

.navbar-brand{
    width: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: .5%;
}
body{
height:2000px;  
}
.dataHeight{
    height: 100vh;
background-color:lightblue;
}

The image would be evenly reduced the more you scroll down and enlarged if the user scrolls up. The image should be reduced to a certain size before it reaches the next element (next element is equivalent to the window height). I am trying to find a formula that would perfectly reduce image size on different-sized monitors.
If more information is needed please tell me

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

JFYI you can do that with css only using animation-timeline :scroll(). Check this link

Just use the CSS Transform/Scale property and adjust the amount with a JavaScript scroll event listener.

Might like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio

Consider the following:
https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1qbth6j8/
HTML
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand fixed-top" id="navbar-brand">
        <img id="cover-image" src="RECMAN-header.png" title="home">
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="dataHeight">
  </div>
</div>

CSS
.navbar-brand {
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 0.5%;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 223px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.dataHeight {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

JavaScript
$(function() {
  var ratio = $("body").height() / $(".navbar-brand img").height();
  console.log("Ratio: " + ratio);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = window.scrollY;
    var newWidth = Math.floor(1024 - (scroll * ratio))
    var newHeight = Math.floor(223 - (scroll))

    var minWidth = 308;
    if (newWidth < minWidth) {
      newWidth = minWidth;
    }
    var minHeight = 64;
    if (newHeight < minHeight) {
      newHeight = minHeight;
    }

    console.log("Scroll: ", newWidth, newHeight);
    $(".navbar-brand img").css({
      width: newWidth + 'px',
      height: newHeight + 'px'
    });
  });
});

As the User scrolls down or up the page, the image is scaled.
